# how to remove form submit message after 10 seconds automatically in the WordPress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, onsubmit

So I m working on a WordPress site I made a form using the formidable plugin. I want the form submitted success message automatically removes after 10 seconds. how to remove form submit message after 10 seconds automatically in the WordPress site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about that plugin but a few lines of JS should do the trick.

Let's say the element that wraps your success message has a class called `notice-container` and the form element has the id `form21`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let container = document.querySelector('.notice-container'),
        form = document.querySelector('#form21');

    if (form != null) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function () {       
            setTimeout(function(){
                container = document.querySelector('.notice-container');
                if (container == null) return; // abort if element isn't available

                container.style.display = 'none';
            }, 10000);
        });
    }
});
```

Place this code anywhere on your page and you're good to go.

P.S: Don't forget to replace the `notice-container` and `form21` values accordingly to your form

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official document of the Formidable form. https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/javascript-examples/javascript-after-form-submit/

You can try something below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".frm_message").delay(10000).fadeOut(1000); // change 5000 to number of seconds in milliseconds  
    });
</script>
```